# Amplifier problem

Tags: amplifiers

I have a Fender Mustang and a Fender SCE acoustic.
this morning I started playing and had no issues everything was fine, I finished playing and when I got back I set everything and played again, this the problem:

I set everything to max and just play but it sounds like it isn't connected,
the amp is on and makes the static sound it usually makes when I'm not playing,
plus the incorporated tuner isn't on (doesn't play if it's on) and I doubt that the cable is broken. what can be the issue?

Comment: Are you going straight from guitar to amp or is there anything else in The chain?

Comment: there is a cable but i don't think it's that

Comment: If you unplug the cable while the amp is on (the end that is in the guitar) (maybe don’t have it turned up ALL the way) do you hear a pop and a crackle? If not do you have a second cable to try?

Comment: if it is attached and i touch it does pop but if i take of it doesn't

Comment: If it is attached to both the amp and the guitar and you touch the cable in the middle somewhere it pops???

Comment: stopped popping... even if i touch the end of the cable

Comment: Do you have a second cable?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103176/discussion-between-francesconirvanafan-and-b3ko).